# 2013 MacBook Air to Lepow Portable Monitor (Cable question)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

Looking for a little insight on a new cable for my travel laptop set up.

I have a portable monitor from Lepow (Amazon).

This monitor has 3 ports and and can accept two input types:

- 2 x USB C (Displayport?) + (Power)
- 1 x Mini HDMI

I also have a 2013 MacBook Air:

This Mac has 1 output type:

- 1 x Thunderbolt (1 or 2) port.

My Current set up:

MacBook Air --> Mini DisplayPort Male to HDMI Female + HDMI Male to Mini HDMI Male --> Lepow Portable Monitor.

Is there a cable that allows me to use my MacBook Air's thunderbolt 2 (DisplayPort) port to connect to the Portable Monitor's type C usb (DisplayPort?) port?

Sorry if this is confusing. Happy to answer any questions.

Thank you!

Sobe

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you can not use a cable, adaptor or combination to connect the MacBook Air Thunderbolt port to a USB port on the monitor. When the Mac and Monitor both have USB Type-C ports which are capable of video and audio transmission and are connected together by a cable with USB Type-C plugs, then then two devices first communicate with each other before switching the ports to a video and audio transmission mode. For this to work you would need a MacBook Air with a USB Type-C port. (I believe this would be 2018 or newer MacBook Air.)

You did not give the model for your Lepow portable monitor. The [user manual](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/919nLxcBT-L.pdf) for the [Z1-Silver model](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RGPCQG1) does not show any configurations which use a Thunderbolt mini Display to USB Type-C cable. The [user guide](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/D1MjOrCAoMS.pdf) specifically states on page 5 a MacBook Air without USB Type-C should use a Thunderbolt mini Display to HDMI adaptor.